# mod rewrite problem

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect my pages using URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/content/(.*)/?(.*)\.html$ browse.php?s=$1&c=$2&l=$3 [NC,L]
```

For 2 parameters it works fine but when I passes 3 parameters it merges the 2 and third.

Correct output is as follow (2) parameters:

```
Array ( [s] => wallpapers [c] => Global_Celebrities [l] => Nicole1);
```

Merged messed output is here (3) parameters:

```
Array ( [s] => wallpapers [c] => Global_Celebrities/Kate1 [l] =>);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you accept the answer that answers your question best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a more specific pattern. Try `[^/]+` instead of `.*`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/content/([^/]+)\.html$ browse.php?s=$1&c=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ browse.php?s=$1&c=$2&l=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you guyz you are the life Savior (K) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to go with 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/content/(\w*)\.html$ browse.php?s=$1&c=$2 [NC,L]<br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)/content/(\w*)/(\w*)\.html$ browse.php?s=$1&c=$2&l=$3 [NC,L]
```

Note, that I am using "\w" instead of ".", so that "." would be unable to eat "/".
It might work with . too, it's just safer with \w.